# Is there a way to use punctuation in Siri dictation?

Tags: ios, siri

Is there a way to use punctuation in Siri dictation? For instance, if I tell Siri to text someone "want to meet for dinner?" - it won't track inflection, right? How can I add the question mark via voice?

Answer (score 19):

http://howto.cnet.com/how-to-make-siri-use-punctuation/8301-11310_39-20124379-285.html

To get Siri to use punctuation, you only need to speak the punctuation during the composition of your message. For example:

> Hi comma how are you question mark did you see the game last night
>   exclamation point question mark.

Speaking that exact line to Siri would equate to the following message:

> Hi, how are you? Did you see the game last night!?

Comment: What would really impress me is if you could say "interrobang" for that last mark. :)

Comment: I appear to have reached me up vote limit today so +1 from me

Answer (score 13):

[CrushApps](http://blog.crushapps.com/2011/10/more-fun-with-siri-dictation/) has a comprehensive list of commands and punctuation that Siri understands.

Here's a short summary as requested by Daniel. These are the ones I find most useful day to day.

- *"all caps on ... all caps off"*: "I am so all caps on hungry all caps off I could eat a horse" -> **I am so HUNGRY I could eat a horse**
- *"exclamation point"*: "You're the man exclamation point" -> **You're the man!**
- *"question mark"*: "What was that question mark" -> **What was that?**
- *"smiley"* or *"smiley face"* or *"smile face"*: "smiley face" -> **:-)**
- *"winky"* or *"winky face"* or *"wink face"*: "wink face" -> **;-)**

But there are many more that include a surprising amount of edge cases. It's possible to dictate the following sentence: *"The number, "pi", is ... 3.14 (approximately)."*

Comment: Can you summarize any of that here, or is it too long?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has added the complete list of punctuation you can dictate to the Knowledge Base.

### [Mac Basics: Dictation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5449)