# Is there a NATIVE way to add punctuation using Dictation on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-dictation

I like using dictation when I’m on my iPhone to speed up text entry but I have a problem when it comes to punctuation. I have been able to fire away at some things like saying “*period*”  or “*question mark*”  for the punctuation symbols period and the question mark respectively.

The answer to this question [Is there a way to use punctuation in Siri dictation?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29564/377857) uses third party Apps or answers about Mac dictation and not iPad’s. I want to use only iOS/iPadOS built-in tools.

Does anyone know of a list of these commands?

Comment: Why would someone down vote me?  Was it a bad question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has an excellent support Document called [Dictate text on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/dictate-text-iph2c0651d2/15.0/ios/15.0#iphd6063ea19) that details this information.

The list of punctuation can be found under the last section of the linked page. Here, I’m listing just a few of the more obscure ones, see the link for the full list:

#### Add punctuation or format text

- “open parenthesis” … “close parenthesis”
- “quote” … “end quote” (I kept saying “quote sign” which didn’t work)
- “caps on” … “caps off” to capitalize the first character of each word
- “no caps on” … “no caps off” to make the enclosed words all lowercase
- “no space” to eliminate the space between two words